# Convert elements within an array into floats in python

Tags: python, arrays

Hi I am quite new to python and what I want to do is simple but I just can't seem to get around it.

I have a simple array as shown below:

```
A1 = [('1.000000', '4.000000'), ('2.000000', '5.000000'), ('3.000000', '6.000000'), ('1.000000', '4.000000'), ('2.000000', '5.000000'), ('3.000000', '6.000000')]
```

I want to change all elements within the array into floats so I can do calculations on them (such as sum etc.). The end results should look something like this:

```
A2 = [(1.000000, 4.000000), (2.000000, 5.000000), (3.000000, 6.000000), (1.000000, 4.000000), (2.000000, 5.000000), (3.000000, 6.000000)]
```

I have tried the following:

```
A2 = [float(i) for i in A1]
```

however I get the error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Could anyone point me towards a solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `i` in your case is a `tuple` with 2 `floats` that's why you get the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one pretty simple way:

```
>>> [map(float, x) for x in A1]
[[1.0, 4.0], [2.0, 5.0], [3.0, 6.0], [1.0, 4.0], [2.0, 5.0], [3.0, 6.0]]
```

I like it's because it's short (some would say terse) and since using `map()` makes it not hardcode or be explicit about the expected format of each `x`, it just says that it assumes `A1` to be a  list of sequences.

I have *no idea* how this compares performance-wise to other solutions (such as the more explicit `[(float(x), float(y) for (x, y) in A1]` seen below).

Answer (score 2):

Each element of A1 is a tuple `('1.000000', '4.000000')`. You will have to convert each item of the tuple:

```
A2 = [(float(i), float(j)) for (i, j) in A1]
```

Comment: @iksalglam If you know that the inner tuples have exactly 2 elements in them, this would be the normal answer.

Comment: Thank you works great!!! But I think it would only work for tuples where I know I have two elements

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the inner tuples as well.

```
A2 = [tuple(float(s) for s in i) for i in A1]
```